# Store a complex object in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I'm writing a chrome extension which needs to store an multidimensional array. 
groupList stores another array.
Whenever retrieving the stored object chrome returns an empty array inside of the object.

```
function Groups(){
  this.groupList = [];
}

//some more Code which fills groupList

function saveGroups(){
  chrome.storage.local.set({'groups':Groups});
}

function loadGroups(){
  chrome.storage.local.get('groups', function (result) {
    var groups = result.groups.groupList;
    Group.groupList.concat(groups);
  });
}
```

loadGroups returns:

```
Object
groupList: Array[0]
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage is string only storage.

Use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` before and after saving your complex object to storage.

Comment: Retrieved object has still an empty array. http://puu.sh/9t4Ng/ee3cbfb9ff.png Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In order to store arrays you would need to do something like this:

```
function saveGroups(){
  chrome.storage.local.set({'groups':{groupList:[]}});
}
```